# Please put the user profile activity sub-menus within an UpdatePanel or at least preserve scroll position

Tags: feature-request, design, profile-page

On the user profile page, clicking any of the sub-menus in the Activity section (such as Questions, Answers, Reputation, All Actions, etc.) causes the whole page to reload, and you loose your scroll position:

[image: Profile jumps back to top when changing sub menu sections]

This is rather jarring. Can we get this section put inside an UpdatePanel (or whatever the .NET Core equivalent is), or at least preserve scroll position?

For example, this feature *is* implemented in the various sub-sub-menus under the "All Actions" sub-menu (e.g. comments, revisions, reviews. etc), and any other sub-sub-menus under other sub-menus as well.